# Integral check for complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

For a fixed $z$ I want to integrate $\int_{C} \frac{1}{(\zeta - z)^{n + 1}} d\zeta$ for a circle $C$ centered at $z$ with radius $\epsilon.$ I parametrized the circle as $\zeta = z + \epsilon e^{i\theta}.$ This gives us $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\epsilon ie^{i\theta}}{(\epsilon e^{i\theta})^{n + 1}} d\theta$$ Which is $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{i}{(\epsilon e^{i\theta})^{n}} d\theta = \frac{-1}{\epsilon n}(\epsilon e^{i\theta})^{n + 1} |_{0}^{2\pi} = 0$$ Is this correct?

Comment: Where does $n$ come from?

Comment: Sorry. Edited to include $n.$

Comment: I presume $n$ is a nonzero integer.

Comment: I should probably be more specific. $n$ is a positive integer, yes.

Comment: "Integral check"... good pun...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you meant $$\int_C \frac{1}{(\zeta-z)^{n+1}}d\zeta$$ in which case you are right up to the line $$ \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{i}{(\epsilon e^{i\theta})^n}d\theta.$$ However, you confuse the power rule with the rule for integrating an exponential. You should have $$ i\epsilon^{-n}\int_0^{2\pi} e^{-in\theta}d\theta = \frac{i\epsilon^{-n}}{-in}\left. e^{-in\theta}\right|_0^{2\pi}. $$
This is still zero... except in one important case where $n=0.$ So the answer is zero for any $n$ other than zero, and when $n=0$ so we have $$\int_C \frac{1}{(\zeta-z)}d\zeta,$$ I'll let you sort that out. (But it's not zero and this fact will turn out to be quite important.)

Comment: As Lord Stark pointed out in the comments, we should also specify $n$ is an integer (I have assumed so here.)

Comment: I see. Thank you for your response! But now i'm wondering how the answer would change if $\frac{1}{(\zeta - z)^{n + 1}}$ were now $|\frac{1}{(\zeta - z)^{n + 1}}|?$ I'm assuming it would make a difference...

Comment: it sure would... Along the circle $\left|\frac{1}{(\zeta-z)^{n+1}}\right|$  takes a rather simple form.

Comment: Note that "it sure would" doesn't necessarily mean it changes the answer in all cases, just that it is a significantly different thing you're integrating and there's no reason you'd expect the answer to be the same at the outset.

Comment: Parametrizing the same way gives us $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\epsilon i e^{i \theta}}{|\epsilon e^{i \theta}|^{n + 1}}.$ But since $|e^{i \theta}| = 1$ we have that the integral is $\frac{i}{\epsilon^{n}} \int_{0}^{2 \pi}  e^{i \theta} = 0.$ So it seems like it is always 0. Are there cases where this isn't true?

Comment: @ntntnt Yep, that's right. No cases where it isn't zero. Integral of a constant around a circle is zero... (just the $n=-1$ case of the first question.